# calculate the address of the subnet in Python

Tags: python

My code:

```
def apply_network_mask(host_address, netmask):
    ip = host_address.split(".")
    net = netmask.split(".")

    ip_1 = int(ip[0])
    ip_2 = int(ip[1])
    ip_3 = int(ip[2])
    ip_4 = int(ip[3])

    net_1 = int(net[0])
    net_2 = int(net[1])
    net_3 = int(net[2])
    net_4 = int(net[3])

    print(f"{ip_1 & net_1} {ip_2 & net_2} {ip_3 & net_3} {ip_4 & net_4}")
```

Result:

```
192 0 0 0
```

What I need is this:

```
192.0.0.0
```

or

```
"192.0.0.0"
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXPoK.png)

Comment: You mean you want the same string you're already printing, but with `.` instead of spaces?

Comment: yes! if possible i would like this "192.0.0.0"

Comment: ... so put `.` in your f-string instead of spaces.

Comment: LOL thx and what do I have to do to get these "192.0.0.0" or [192,0,0,0]

Comment: What do you mean? You already have `"192.0.0.0"` because it's a string. If you want a list just change it to a list `[ip_1 & net_1, ip_2 & net_2, ip_3 & net_3, ip_4 & net_4]`

Comment: yea sorry bro you are right + thx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, you can add '.' in your print format.

And it is not recommended to assign list items into individual variable.
You can accomplish this with below code instead

```py
def apply_network_mask(host_address, netmask):
    print('.'.join([str(int(a)&int(b)) for a,b in zip(host_address.split('.'),netmask.split('.'))]))
```

Comment: what's wrong with assigning list items to variables?

Comment: It's not the best coding practice, especially when list can be of variable size.